# replace line by bullets before category lists in dropdown menu

Tags: css, catalogsearch

please visit this link :

http://demo.kidsdial.com/

on top you can see search box with "all categories", you can see there is a dropdown menu.

if we hover mouse on that"drop down menu" button, you can see list of "categories and sub-

categories". before every category name there is a line displaying.

I want to remove that line and put "bullet symbol", before all categories.

please help me to get some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a standard magento feature. I assume you have a custom extension that adds the categories to the search.
Look in the files of that extension for the code that generates the list of categories and instead of `-` use `&bull;` or simply `•`

**[EDIT]**
In the file `EM\Em0113settings\Helper\Data.php` look for the method `getCatNameCustom`.
Inside it there is this line `$html .= '&mdash;&ndash;';`. Replace it with `$html .= '&bull;&bull;';`

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply for my post after long days.

i will try and tell you as early as possible....

Comment: this is the file which generating that catalog search : http://pastebin.com/nJJ6Qksz

there are underscore , i did't found "-" sybmol.

can you please tell me in which line i have to edit the code?

Comment: I think you have to search in the method `getCategoriesCustom` called at line 39. Locate the helper with the alias `em0113settings`. that's where the method is.

Comment: is i have to change line no : 39, i can not able to get the solution. can you please tell me in detail....

Comment: Look inside the extension you are using, for the file `Helper/Data.php` inside it, you should find a method called `getCategoriesCustom `. That's the one that returns the categories.

Comment: this is data.php = > http://pastebin.com/Sp4Amaji

Comment: that's not the right helper. You can add somewhere in your templtate this `echo get_class(Mage::helper('em0113settings'))` and see the exact class used.

Comment: can you please tell me in which file, i have to add this code?

Comment: if you help for this, i believe i will get answer for this too : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55485/different-colors-for-different-types-of-categories-and-sub-categories-in-magento/55493#55493

Comment: @user9434334345 add it in the template file. The one you pasted here: http://pastebin.com/nJJ6Qksz

Comment: this code is  already in inside form.mini.phtml file, 

but sorry i did't mentioned here. now do you want to add in another file [example : otherfile.phtml] inside as like

app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/otherfile.phtml

Comment: form.mini.phtml is in inside app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml

Comment: hi marius, sorry for delay. i got reply from emthemes. in em themes they use helper of theme module to load it . we can open file app\design\frontend\default\em0113\template\catalogsearch\form.mini.phtml
This file will call function "getCategoriesCustom" in file :
app\code\community\EM\Em0113settings\Helper\Data.php
In Data.php file , you can find function "getCategoriesCustom" and we can edit....

Comment: Data.php = http://pastebin.com/T8PSVL9c

Comment: @user9434334345. See my update