# different colors for different types of categories and sub categories in magento

Tags: css, catalogsearch, category-tree, color-swatches

please visit this link : http://demo.kidsdial.com/

on top of the site, you can see "catalog search box "all categories" and search box.

if you hover mouse on dropdown symbol next to "all categories" text, you can see all categories.

a)ALL CATEGORIES
b)BOYS TOYS
c)ACTION & TOY FIGURES.

I want to give different colors for a) and b) and c)

pleas help me to find solution.

Comment: cannot unserstard

Comment: means i want to give different colors for a)ALL CATEGORIES b)BOYS TOYS c)ACTION & TOY FIGURES.

pleaase use dropdown menu next to all categories "v" symbol.... let me know if you have any doubts in question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should find out where and how in your "Best Friends" theme the list of categories is generated.

   > This depends on your custom theme. So I'm not able to advise on where
   >   and how this is done. You could ask EM Themes where to look.
2. Then add different class names to the list elements, like `class="topcat"`, `class="subcat"` and `class="childcat"`. The result of the list should look like this.

   ```
   <div class="catsearch-dropdown">
       <span class="current">—– All Categories</span>
           <ul style="opacity: 0; display: none;" class="">
               <li class="topcat">—– All Categories</li>
               <li class="subcat">—–—– Boys Toys</li>
               <li class="childcat">—–—–—– Action &amp; Toy Figures</li>
               <li class="childcat">—–—–—– Arts &amp; Crafts</li>
               <li class="childcat">—–—–—– Bikes, Trikes &amp; Ride-Ons</li>
               <li class="childcat">—–—–—– Building Sets &amp; Blocks</li>
               ...
           </ul>
   </div>
   ```
3. Then add the following `<CSS>` to your `styles.css` file

   ```
   .catsearch-dropdown ul li.topcat {
       color: #090;
   }
   .catsearch-dropdown ul li.subcat {
       color: #f00;
   }
   .catsearch-dropdown ul li.childcat {
       color: #03f;
   }
   ```
4. The final result should look something like this

   [image]

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply. very clearly explained.

can you tell me about where in  default magento theme, where list of categories will come....

is there any option to find where list of categories will generate....

Comment: when i used template path hints, i saw it came from here :


frontend/default/em0113/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml : http://pastebin.com/qW35ttwa.

what changes i have to do now

Comment: This is the template file which inserts the "search-by-category" widget. But it pulls the list of categories from somewhere else. I think you should be looking in `app/code/community/EM/...` or `app/code/local/EM/...` and see if you can find the code there. But the quickest thing is to just send EMThemes an email and ask them where to find the code. Giao usually responds very quickly to support requests.

Comment: em themes replied as follows.....

in em themes they use helper of theme module to load it . we can open file app\design\frontend\default\em0113\template\catalogsearch\form.mini.phtml
This file will call function "getCategoriesCustom" in file :
app\code\community\EM\Em0113settings\Helper\Data.php
In Data.php file , you can find function "getCategoriesCustom" and we can edit....

Comment: Data.php =http://pastebin.com/T8PSVL9c